# u.i.Bootstrap Modals not working?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I want to hide "not same" the very moment password matches. It is not working as it is in plunker. Although i have achieved what I wished by doing this:

```
ng-hide="obj.newpass==obj.retypepass";
```

But I want to know, that can I do something like this : http://plnkr.co/edit/m2KoL8VAbm1gIWJWsZ7u?p=preview.

Objects created Inside modals can be accessed outside while it is open ?

A corrected plunker will be helpful.

Comment: I'm by no means an expert in this but if you want to keep synced data between controllers, you can either build a factory method with shared data and inject it in these controllers or use $rootScope and $broadcast. Plenty of examples for both if you look around.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, use .value
here's demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/wbbzGPKXkjxb1j5J8BSG?p=preview

reason being, modal controller is not in child scope of your main controller. .factory, .value .constant can also be used

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. Please [edit] the post and update the answer.

Answer (score 1):

`mike()` is not really needed. just change the ng-hide condition from `a` to `obj.newpass == obj.retypepass`

[see here](http://plnkr.co/edit/rBuQcQ9hCq1gsDqHkeOc?p=preview)

Comment: thats what I did. Its mentioned in question, but i want to know if it can be done in the way my plunker shows.